# It showed video system not initialized

Tags: python, pygame

So i jsut started learning python but right now when i run this and try to jump it loads this error and also the rectangle dont move if i hold it it only moves onces i just started and i really dont know what the problem is

This is what it showed: keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() pygame.error: video system not initialized

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello")

x = 100
y = 100
width = 50
height = 50
vel = 10

jump_count = 10
jump = False
run = True

while run:
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():


    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()


    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 450:
        x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 0:
        x -= vel
    if not jump:
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 450:
            y += vel
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 0:
            y -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            jump = True
    else:
        if jump_count >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jump_count < 0:
                neg = -1

            y -= (jump_count ** 2) /2 * neg
            jump_count = -1
        else:
            jump = False
            jump_count = 10


    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). Correct the indentation of your code and it will work fine.

Don't uninitialize all pygame modules in the event loop. Terminate the application loop and call [`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) after the application loop:

```py
run = True

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # [...]

pygame.quit()
```

Use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed.

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time.
That means that the loop:

> ```py
> clock = pygame.time.Clock()
> run = True
> while run:
>    clock.tick(60)
> ```

runs 60 times per second.

In addition, your code contains a typo. You have to decrement the variable `jump_count` than setting it to -1:

`jump_count = -1`

```py
jump_count -= 1
```

---

Working code:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello")

x = 100
y = 100
width = 50
height = 50
vel = 10

jump_count = 10
jump = False
run = True

while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 450:
        x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 0:
        x -= vel
    if not jump:
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 450:
            y += vel
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 0:
            y -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            jump = True
    else:
        if jump_count >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jump_count < 0:
                neg = -1

            y -= (jump_count ** 2) /2 * neg
            jump_count -= 1
        else:
            jump = False
            jump_count = 10

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```